# What does this small 'A' mean next to my files in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

So I dragged a few files into a new Xcode project and notice that the files I dragged in had little 'A's next to them. Does anybody know what this means?

[image]

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16670942/1405155

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That is the SCM (git, SVN, etc.) status of the file. 'A' stands for Added, 'M' stands for Modified, and '?' stands for Unknown (i.e. untracked file).

Xcode 4 creates a git repo for new projects by default. You can disable this on the New Project dialog if you wish.

Comment: What does A+ mean? Ah apparently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892827/xcode-5-source-control-a-symbol it means file name change.

Comment: what about R? what is it supposed to stand for?

Comment: Here you can find more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754850/symbols-meaning-aside-class-name-in-xcode

Answer (score 4):

It means the file's version control status is "added". See the [Xcode documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/SCM/SCM.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH7-SW27) for more details.

Comment: dude, total accident, if you edit your comment it should let me change it. haha sorry!