# Xcode A+ source control symbol

Tags: xcode, git, version-control, symbols

I've just noticed that XCode shows "A+" symbol related with source control. What does it mean?

Comment: A+ means the file has been moved.

More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034/what-do-the-result-codes-in-svn-mean

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A+ stands for moving a file (renaming is treated as moving). All credit goes to user2129800, whose answer is in the comment under the question.

Comment: Maybe changing the name causes A+ but I have a file with A+ and its name never changed. The reason must be something more general.

Comment: Not sure that moving is the only reason. I just created a class and coded a bit. Now .h has "A" aka New, and .m somehow has "A+". I did not move or rename anything.

Comment: Sometimes, when you delete a source and add a new file, very similar to the deleted one, version control will skip D and A states and mark it as A+ (rename).